# login in page doesn't redirect with CakePHP ACL

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I am following the CakePHP ACL tutorial
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

I have a controller called ImagesController that basically lets the user list all the images that have been uploaded. There are also actions such as "upload" and "delete" images.

I also have a UserController that has login and logout function.

My AppController.php looks like this

```
  1 <?php
  2 
  3 class AppController extends Controller {
  4     public $components = array(
  5             'Acl',
  6             'Auth' => array(
  7                 'authorize' => array(
  8                     'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
  9                     )
 10                 ),
 11             'Session'
 12             );
 13     public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
 14 
 15     public function beforeFilter() {
 16  //       $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';
 17         //Configure AuthComponent
 18         $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
 19         $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
 20         $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index');
 21         $this->Auth->allow('display');
 22  //       $this->Auth->allow('*');
 23     }
 24 }
 25 
 26 
 27 ?>
~
```

My UsersController.php looks like this

```
<?php
  2 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
  3 /**
  4  * Users Controller
  5  *
  6  * @property User $User
  7  */
  8 class UsersController extends AppController {
 30     public function beforeFilter() {
 31         parent::beforeFilter();
 32         //$this->Auth->allow("initDB"); // remove this later
 33         $this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout');
 34     }
 35     public function login() {
 36         if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
 37             $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
 38             $this->redirect('/', null, false);
 39         }
 40     }
 41     public function logout() {
 42         //Leave empty for now.
 43         $this->Session->setFlash('Good-Bye');
 44         $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
 45     }
}
```

So now when I click on an action in images/index such as upload or delete, it sends me to user/login page but when I try to log in nothing happens, even though I have my redirect pointed to images/index in line 20. What gives?

Comment: Any `beforeFilter()` method in your `UsersController` that forgets to call `parent::beforeFilter()` maybe ?

Comment: No I have parent::beforeFilter(); in my beforeFilter() UsersController. What else can it be?

Comment: Updated with UsersController.php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Cake 1.3, in Cake 2, the login is not done automatically. This means you have to call `$this->Auth->login()` explicitely.

Have a look at the login() action in the [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#preparing-to-add-auth). So far, you never perform the login, and that explains why you are not redirected.

Comment: Damn! I am not even sure why I had different code from the tutorial. Thanks that worked. I have 2 groups one is admin and one is visitors. Right now admin can add and upload images and visitors can just view the images, if they click add or delete, it won't let them do anything. What's the best way to remove these links for visitor group? If I check which group they belong to using if/else statement, would that be the best solution?

Comment: I wanted to answer you, but my answer is too long for a comment. I think it worths a new question, also because I would love to know how other Cake users manage that on their side.

Comment: Ok I created a new post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540747/cakephp-acl-generating-different-links-for-different-groups

Comment: btw. Do you have aim or gmail? Would love to chat more about cakephp with you since it doesn't seem to be that popular on here.