# CakePHP ACL generating different links for different groups

Tags: php, cakephp

Using CakePHP 2.0's ACL I have created 2 groups. One is admin and one is visitors. Right now admin can add and upload images and visitors can just view the images, if they click add or delete, it won't let them do anything. What's the best way to remove these links for visitor group? If I check which group they belong to using if/else statement, would that be the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

To hide links that lead to actions a user is not authorized to perform, the views must somehow be aware of the user permissions. 
You could check these permissions by checking the group a user belongs to, but this would mean that you wouldn't rely on the ACL permissions anymore. So any ACL permission update would have to be reported in code. Not very handy.

Then what else ? An approach is to check the user permissions in the controller, typically during login, and then keep these permissions in session.
The permissions in session can then be checked in the views to hide or show some parts of the views. You can find an example of this method [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/thanos/2011/01/17/acl_checking_permissions_in_views):

But for links specifically, you can go a little further and avoid to write the tests in views. I personnaly use a helper that inherits from the HtmlHelper and overrides the link() method.
Basically it works on the same idea: inside the overriden link() method, the permission on the target action is checked and the helper return the link, or nothing if the user is not allowed to access the target action.

If you want to try my code, you can use my [Acl plugin](http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0)

In your AppController, set the permissions:

```
var $components = array(..., 'Acl.AclManager');

function beforeFilter()
{
    ...
    //you can put it here as the permissions check is performed only once per session
    $this->AclManager->set_session_permissions();
    ...
}
```

And in your views, use the AclHtmlHelper

```
$this->AclHtml->link(...);
```

A general remark on the principle this method is based on though: all permissions are checked during login. If you have many actions in your application, this can considerably slow down the login.

A more effective approach could be to check the user permission for each actions only when it is required, meaning when the link() method is called. But this would mean that the helper would have to check the Acl permission itself, and this would somehow break the MVC model. And in the core lib, the Acl check is highly coupled to a component.

Comment: Will it affect the performance if I have many controllers(around 100 and) each controller has 5 or more methods?

Comment: @gvLearner As I mentionned, it affects the login time, because as soon as a user is authenticated, the permissions are checked. In your case, the AclComponent->check() method would be called around 500 times at login. This is clearly a drawback. But then, once the login is done, it almost does not affect performance (only a few calls to some `Router` methods are used to compare the action link and the permissions in session).